# Elasicsearch in different region don't see each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

My question is 2 fold:
*********UPDATE****************
I fixed number 1.
I had to specify the region in the config. I guess this is because my keys associate the east by default.
If anyone has an answer to 2 that would be great.

1) I am ultimately trying to setup a 4 node cluster (2 in each region). In the main region (east-us-1) the nodes see each other perfectly fine but in the west, they don't seem to see each other. I'd like to make sure they can see each other before I try multi region (which I'm not entirely sure how to do yet). I've installed the plugin.
Basically, why in a different region are the nodes not seeing each other when it's the same config. I can telnet to/from each server on 9200/9300.
Here is my config:

cloud:
    aws:
      access_key: 
      secret_key:

discovery:
   type: ec2
   ec2:
     groups: ELASTIC-SEARCH

2) Is there a way to designate a specific node to "Hold all the data" and then distribute it among them all?

Comment: When I start node 1 I *should* get an error saying it cannot reach the second node in that security group. Example on the east region:[2014-02-18 16:03:47,408][TRACE][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [Ezekiel Stane] [1] failed to connect to [#cloud-i-00b8ed2e-0][localhost.localdomain][inet[/10.110.65.92:9300]] Once the second node is started it connect. That error I believe is only there because there is another elasticnode in that security group, it's just not started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not the answer you want: *Don't do that*.

It'll be *much* easier to have two clusters in two regions, and keep them in sync on your application layer. Also, Elasticsearch has introduced the concept of a Tribe-node in 1.0 to make this a bit easier.

Elasticsearch, like any distributed database, is very sensitive to network issues. In this case you're relying on the Internet working reliably. It tends not to.

The setup you suggest will be quite prone to split brains or outages. If you configure minimum master nodes to be a quorum, which you always should, the cluster will go down whenever there's a connection problem between the regions.

We've written two articles that go much more in depth than this about this topic, which you may want to look into:

- [Elasticsearch in Production](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-in-production/#networking) has a section on networking related issues.
- [Elasticsearch Internals: Networking Introduction](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-networking/) describes the network topology of Elasticsearch. Specifically, you'll see just how many connections Elasticsearch needs to have working reliably.

Comment: Thank you!! Right now I'm having an issue where the west region can see the east but is unable to connect. I am getting this:[2014-02-19 10:43:02,196][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [Cyclops] failed to send ping to [[#cloud-i-47742169-0][localhost.localdomain][inet[/10.110.65.91:9300]]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][inet[/10.110.65.91:9300]][discovery/zen/unicast] request_id [2] timed out after [3750ms]